# Can you transfer money from a smart contract to an eth address without writing code?

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp

I have an ethereum contract, which linked to a wallet that I control (i.e. I have the private key).

The contract has 241 Ether in it. Is there an easy tool available to get the ether out of the contract? Or do I need to use the command line and operate on the contract to get the money to transfer?

Metamask, MEW and Ledger tools have, so far, not let me operate on the contract. I have geth on my machines too, but I'd prefer something point and click so I don't transpose a digit or something and mess anything up..

Thanks,

Comment: The answer is simple: yes - if you have implemented a function in this contract which does `msg.sender.send` or `msg.sender.transfer` (or instead of `msg.sender`, some other address of an account which you control (i.e., have the private key of)). otherwise - no.

Comment: What do you mean by "linked"? You can not own a contract, you can only have your address stored in it to allow you to call certain functions

Comment: To be more specific. The contract is a multisig wallet. So I own the address that allows me to interact with the contract. Sorry if linked is the wrong word.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the contract exposes some sort of simple transfer function, `https://etherscan.io/address/<contract address>#writeContract` is a pretty easy-to-use interface. Add the address to MetaMask (via the private key), and then use Etherscan to call whatever method you want on the contract.